# Is it possible to climb Uluru (Ayers Rock)?

Tags: australia, landmarks, mountain-climbing, uluru

Suppose I'm in Australia. Can I climb [Uluru](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulu%E1%B9%9Fu)? Do I need any special permits or gear? And how long do I have to walk to the top?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

EDIT: As of October 26, 2019, [it is no longer permitted to climb](https://www.ayersrockresort.com.au/uluru-and-kata-tjuta/uluru-and-kata-tjuta-national-park/can-i-climb-uluru).

(The final weeks before the ban have caused an [embarrassing level of climbers](https://www.smh.com.au/politics/federal/it-s-a-tidal-wave-tourists-flock-to-uluru-as-ban-on-climbing-approaches-20191017-p531nx.html) to 'beat the ban')

Yes it's possible.  The question is - should you?

From [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Uluru-Kata_Tjuta_National_Park):

> To climb or not to climb
>
> Uluru is sacred to the Anangu people of the area. They say that the
>   climb follows the track that the ancestoral Mala men took to get to
>   the top for ceremony. They say that when you climb, you are on their
>   tracks.
>
> In addition, there are some safety and environmental concerns - at
>   least 35 people have died whilst climbing Uluru - albeit most
>   accidents occur when leaving the marked trail. There are no toilet
>   facilities on the track or on top of Uluru. As a result, bacterial
>   levels in the waterholes at the base of the rock are significantly
>   higher then those further away from the rock.
>
> The climb is also closed for various reasons; From 8am in Summer
>   months (December, January and February), Heat (if temperature reaches
>   36 degrees), Rain (greater then 20% chance of rain/5% chance of
>   thunderstorms in 3 hours), Wind (Speed at summit reaches 25 knots),
>   Wet (if 20% of surface is wet after rain), Cloud (if there is cloud
>   below the summit), Rescue (if there is a rescue from the rock), or
>   Culture (if the traditional owners request closure, for example during
>   mourning periods).
>
> The decision to climb when it is open is yours - but make sure you are
>   properly informed before you decide. Visit the Cultural Centre first
>   to learn more about the park and what makes Uluru so significant.

Around the mountain you have a few options:

- The climb. If you have decided to climb, the best bet is to start early - the climb will be closed if the temperature is forecast to be hot. It is about a 1km walk to the top following a worn path with a chain. Remember there are no toilet facilities on the walk. If you aren't persuaded by the cultural arguments, then the view from the top of the rock is nice, and worth the climb. The walk is steep, but if you are fit, stay to the track, carry water, and avoid the heat of the day, it should present no extraordinary hazards.
- The Uluru base walk (9.8km) and will take 3-4 hours. Most people walk clockwise on the track but a few kilometres along this track the crowds thin out to just an occasional walker.
- The Mala Walk (2 km) This track begins at the Mala Walk car-park and ends at the inspiring Kantju Gorge.
- The Liru Walk is a walk between the cultural centre and the base of Uluru. It's 4km and takes about 1 and a half hours.
- The Kuniya Walk is an easy 1km walk to the Mutitjulu Waterhole on the Southern side of Uluru. There is some rock art here also in the rock shelter, and a good place to learn about the Tjukurpa (pronounced Chook-a-pa) of the area.

Comment: thanks. nice answer. i never saw it from that perspective.

Comment: [To climb or not to climb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPzc6gqSw-8)

Answer (score 28):

As of October 26th 2019, it will not be possible to climb Uluru:

> In line with the agreed process in the Uluru-Kata Tjuta National Park Management Plan 2010-2020 and the wishes of traditional owners, the climb to the top of Uluru will close on 26 October 2019.

https://www.environment.gov.au/mediarelease/uluru-climb-close

Answer (score 10):

As Mark's answer says it is currently permitted to climb Uluru when it's not closed for safety reasons etc.

But it does come up in the news from time to time that it might be closed completely!

[If you do some web searching you can find plenty of articles at least in the 2009 to 2011 period concerning this.](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=close%20OR%20closure%20OR%20%22shut%20down%22%20OR%20ban%20OR%20stopping%20climb%20uluru%20OR%20%22ayers%20rock%22)

So yes it's open for now, but there is a real possibility that it might not always be.

Remember though, if it is ever closed down completely, it will be out of respect for the site's original owners. The reason that it is currently open to climb is from the original owners' respect for visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do this.  Uluru is sacred to the Pitjantjatjara Anangu.  You wouldn't like if if some foreigner came to your country and started climbing up your sacred monument.

---

**Since there seems no other way to comment on the deletion of my answer:**

I did read Craig's (very recent) answer but didn't think it came over as a definite "don't do it" kind of advice, nor do I think answers should seem to endorse "you can get away with it, if you hurry up".

So, yes, this is an answer.  And I think my indignation at the idea of climbing over other people's monuments just because you can get away with it, is the right approach.  However, having said this, I did not notice the date was from years ago (something that has happened to me several times before when recent answers/comments from others cause an old question to bubble to the top again).

Like you, I too chose not to climb when I visited in 2004.  There was a big sign at the start of the path.

Comment: While I agree with your sentiment (and already did before I walked around it back in 2005,) I do not think this is an answer. If you read the answer by @Craig Curtis you will see that soon it is not possible at all. OP has asked this question years ago, which makes this comment a bit off as well.

Comment: I still do not think this an answer but I leave it to the community to decide. (Your point was already made in the first part of the accepted answer.)